# Verilog Testbench Won't Compile - Multiple Definitions

Tags: verilog

I am building NANDLAND's UART transmitter and receiver (https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/module-uart-serial-port-rs232.html) and got to the point of implementing the testbench. When I compile the testbench I get the error:

```
Error (10228): Verilog HDL error at uart_tx.v(1): module "uart_tx" cannot be declared more than once
```

I have 3 files: uart_tx.v, uart_rx.v and uart_tb.v all in the same folder with uart_tb set as my top-level entity. All replicas of NANDLAND's code.

Much appreciated!

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps
 
`include "uart_tx.v"
`include "uart_rx.v"
 
module uart_tb ();
 
  // Testbench uses a 10 MHz clock
  // Want to interface to 115200 baud UART
  // 10000000 / 115200 = 87 Clocks Per Bit.
  parameter c_CLOCK_PERIOD_NS = 100;
  parameter c_CLKS_PER_BIT    = 87;
  parameter c_BIT_PERIOD      = 8600;
   
  reg r_Clock = 0;
  reg r_Tx_DV = 0;
  wire w_Tx_Done;
  reg [7:0] r_Tx_Byte = 0;
  reg r_Rx_Serial = 1;
  wire [7:0] w_Rx_Byte;
   
 
  // Takes in input byte and serializes it 
  task UART_WRITE_BYTE;
    input [7:0] i_Data;
    integer     ii;
    begin
       
      // Send Start Bit
      r_Rx_Serial <= 1'b0;
      #(c_BIT_PERIOD);
      #1000;
       
       
      // Send Data Byte
      for (ii=0; ii<8; ii=ii+1)
        begin
          r_Rx_Serial <= i_Data[ii];
          #(c_BIT_PERIOD);
        end
       
      // Send Stop Bit
      r_Rx_Serial <= 1'b1;
      #(c_BIT_PERIOD);
     end
  endtask // UART_WRITE_BYTE
   
   
  uart_rx #(.CLKS_PER_BIT(c_CLKS_PER_BIT)) UART_RX_INST
    (.i_Clock(r_Clock),
     .i_Rx_Serial(r_Rx_Serial),
     .o_Rx_DV(),
     .o_Rx_Byte(w_Rx_Byte)
     );
   
  uart_tx #(.CLKS_PER_BIT(c_CLKS_PER_BIT)) UART_TX_INST
    (.i_Clock(r_Clock),
     .i_Tx_DV(r_Tx_DV),
     .i_Tx_Byte(r_Tx_Byte),
     .o_Tx_Active(),
     .o_Tx_Serial(),
     .o_Tx_Done(w_Tx_Done)
     );
 
   
  always
    #(c_CLOCK_PERIOD_NS/2) r_Clock <= !r_Clock;
 
   
  // Main Testing:
  initial
    begin
       
      // Tell UART to send a command (exercise Tx)
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      r_Tx_DV <= 1'b1;
      r_Tx_Byte <= 8'hAB;
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      r_Tx_DV <= 1'b0;
      @(posedge w_Tx_Done);
       
      // Send a command to the UART (exercise Rx)
      @(posedge r_Clock);
      UART_WRITE_BYTE(8'h3F);
      @(posedge r_Clock);
             
      // Check that the correct command was received
      if (w_Rx_Byte == 8'h3F)
        $display("Test Passed - Correct Byte Received");
      else
        $display("Test Failed - Incorrect Byte Received");
       
    end
   
endmodule
```

Comment: I'm using Quartus Prime Lite Edition. I'm not 100% sure which compiler I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the  `` `include "uart_tx.v" `` lines in your testbench file. I'm assuming they are already part of your compilation command that you did not show us.